# NullPointerException on insertion in TrieNode

Tags: java, trie

I have the following code in which I am trying to implement addWord(..) algorithm to TrieNode.
 AutoCompleteDictionaryTrie.java

```
 public boolean addWord(String word) {
   // TODO: Implement this method
   char[] chArr = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
   int length = word.length();
   boolean flag = false;
   TrieNode tNode = null;
   int i = 0;
   for (char c: chArr) {
    tNode = root.insert(c);
    i++;
    if (i == length) {
     tNode.setEndsWord(true);
     flag = true;
    }
    size++;
    return flag;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isWord(String s) {
    // TODO: Implement this method
    char[] chArr = s.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    boolean flag = false;
    TrieNode tNode = root;
    String rStr = "";
    int i = 0, length = s.length();
    for (char c: chArr) {
     tNode = tNode.getChild(c);
     rStr += c;
     if (i == length && tNode.endsWord()) {
      if (rStr.equals(s.toLowerCase()))
       flag = true;
     }
     i++;
    }
    return flag;
   }
```

in `addWord(..)` if I insert `team` first and then `tea` I get the `NullPointerException`

```
TrieNode.java

public TrieNode getChild(Character c)
    {
        return children.get(c);
    }

    public TrieNode insert(Character c)
    {
        if (children.containsKey(c)) {
            return null;
        }

        TrieNode next = new TrieNode(text + c.toString());
        children.put(c, next);
        return next;
    }


    public String getText()
    {
        return text;
    }


    public void setEndsWord(boolean b)
    {
        isWord = b;
    }


    public boolean endsWord()
    {
        return isWord;
    }
```

I dont want add any new method in `TrieNode` to fullfill it. I have tried to use `getChildren()` method that would return `HashMap<Character, TrieNode> children` object but that was of no use either. Please help me fix this. I am sure I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by:

```
    if (children.containsKey(c)) {
        return null;
    }
```

For insert word *team* and *tea*, they both start with *t*, the above code will return `null` for *tea* term. but in the below code snippet, it's still calling `setEndsWord`, so it will throw `NullPointerException`

```
tNode.setEndsWord(true);
```

Comment: but shouldn't we need to end the word when the `char` is complete?